# How to stream Multicast Stream over rtsp in vlc?

Tags: rtsp

I would like to do multicast streaming over rtsp in vlc either from GUI or from terminal. Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

You may create config file, something like:

```
new ch1 broadcast enabled
setup ch1 input "C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos\Wildlife.wmv"
setup ch1 output #transcode{vcodec="h264",vb="600"}:rtp{dst=239.255.1.1,port=1234,sdp=rtsp://localhost:5554/test1}
control ch1 play
```

Run vlc with the next command: *vlc -I telnet --vlm-conf < config file >*

Stream is available at *rtsp://localhost:5554/test1*